# Spring Boot: Rest URL returns 404

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I am developing a simple Spring Boot base rest application which has been deployed into an external tomcat server, with jndi data source. When I run the application the database gets created, this means the application is able to read the Entity classes and create hibernate ddl. However, when I try to hit the rest url from postman a 404 error message is returned. This has happened after I have moved my application to an external server, when I was using the embeded server I was able to hit the urls. Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
Main method:

package com.nb;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBootWithSpringDataJpaApplication.class);
}

Controller:
package com.nb.springboot.topic;
@RestController
public class TopicController {

@Autowired
private TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return topicService.getAllTopics();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/topics")
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic){
        topicService.addTopic(topic);

    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/topics/{id}")
    public void updateTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic, @PathVariable String id){
        topicService.updateTopic(topic, id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/topics/{id}")
    public void deleteTopic(@PathVariable String id){
        topicService.deleteTopic(id);
    }
```

}

http://localhost:8080/topics/java  ---- works with embedded server

http://localhost8080/topics/java  ------ does not work in tomcat 8(external)

http://localhost8080/SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA/topics/java  ------ does not work in tomcat 8(external) where SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA is my project name.

The application.properties file is :

spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres/springbootDS

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Comment: I suspect it is because when you deploy to an external server it is actually deployed into a web context.  Open the tomcat manager to see what the context is, your url will look like http://localhost:8080/{context}/topics/java

Comment: If you use maven its most (if dont changed the version) something like `localhost:8080/SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/...`

Comment: Ohh Thank you so much. I am using maven and the war that gets generated has name SpringBootWithSpringDataJPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. I forgot to change the name. Guess this was dumb! Thanks ton!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the app name in the url, like:

```
localhost:8080/appname/topics/java
```

or if you use maven should be:

```
localhost:8080/appnameX.X.X-SNAPSHOT/topics/java...
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue with the url call, I am using maven so war gets generated with X.X.X-SNAPSHOT. Totally missed it.